# Weka disabled 'start' button for Association rule generation

Tags: csv, weka, market-basket-analysis

I'm using `Weka explorer` for generating association rules aka `Market Basket Analysis`. I have my data in a `csv` file. to begin with, I had about 200,000 records with 59 variables in the `csv` file and it took more than 3 hours to run and I still didn't get the results.

As a result, I tried to remove most records and left only 5,000 records in the file. Now when I try to run the same association rule, the `Start` button is disabled.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Any recommendations from anyone?